# Получения указателя на свойство в объекте, для изменения его атррибута

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть класс генератор, поставляющий экземпляры произвольных классов, предварительно меняя значении , согласно настройкам их полей. Настройки хранятся в аттрибутах.

```
 public class Generator<T> where T: new()
    {
       public T Generate(Random rnd)
        {... return value;}

    }

    public class T1
    {
       [FromDistribution(typeof(NormalDistribution), 1, 2)]
        public double A { get; set; }

       [FromDistribution(typeof(ExponentialDistribution), 4)]
       [DisplayName("B-value")]
        public double B { get; set; }
    }
```

Проблема в том что генератор должен поддерживать возможность смены настроек по API

```
  var newBDistr = new NormalDistribution(1, 1);
            var generator = new Generator<T1>()
                .For(z => z.A)
                .Set(newADistr)
                .For(z => z.B)
                .Set(newBDistr);
```

Предполагал реализовать селектор(FOR) такой сигнатуры

```
  public Generator<T> For(Func<T, object> function)
        {...}
```

Но в таком формате на выход "functon" приходит double как задано в описании класса T2 что не позволяет определить какое поле должно быть модифицированно в Set.

Очевидно подход не подходит. Но более корректный , не нарушающий api придумать не могу. 
Буду благодарен за идеи.

Comment: Передавайте `Expression<Func<T, object>> expression` и разбирайте его

Comment: @АндрейNOP Верно, сигнатура подходит, спасибо, продолжу копать в этом направлении.

Comment: А в чем смысл разделять For и Set ? Почему это 2 функции, а не одна? Например, `.Set(x=>x.MyField = 8)`

Comment: @tym32167 никакого смысла, условия задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как итог. Сигнатура

```
Expression <Func<T, object>> и  Func<T, object>
```

одинаковая. Оба можно передавать в метод как LINQ.

Для z => z.A название поля можно получить серией кастов :

```
ISmth For(Expression<Func<T, object>> function)
        {
            var expression = function.Body;
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            var name =  memberExpression.Member.Name;

            operandName = name;

            return ISmth;
        }
```

Comment: Думаю, вам придется создать классы производные от Generator и возвращать их из метода. После `For`, например, это должен быть уже не просто генератор, а генератор с выбранным членом, чтобы на следующем шаге вы могли этой дополнительной информацией воспользоваться и установить выбранному члену значение. Т.е. будет что-то вроде `return new GeneratorWithSelectedMember(this, name);`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Верно, для повышения читабельности и корректности логично было бы  связь For и Set оформить каким либо контрактом. Но это выходит за рамки обсуждения. Спасибо за комментарий, простите если вопросы ввели вас в заблуждение, заменил на нейтральный интерфейс.